Find all prefixes of a word that are stored in a binary search tree
I have a binary search tree storing strings. The strings are compared lexicographically (with strcmp in c).
Given some input string, I want to retrieve a list of all the prefixes of that string that are stored in the BST. For example, if my BST contains 'a', 'ab', and 'abc', such a search should return a list of these three strings, given the input string 'abcd' (detail: if the BST contains the string itself, it is considered a prefix).
The naive approach would be to test if the BST contains every prefix of the string one by one (for 'hello', search for 'h', 'he', 'hel',...), but I'd like a more efficient approach that avoids traversing multiple times the same node.
How would you do this? I've been thinking about this for a while but can never seem to figure it out.
I've noticed that, if at a node, a prefix is found, then all nodes to the left of that node may only contain a shorter prefix, and all nodes to the right only a longer one. I, however, don't quite know how this would help.
My implementation for the BST is simple:
typedef struct Node_t
{
    Node* left, *right; // NULL if no node to either side
    const char* key; // Every node has an associated key
} Node;

typedef struct BST_t
{
    Node* root;
    size_t nNodes;
} BST;

For the insertion/search, I call strcmp(string, node->key), and if the result is >0, I go to the right child, and if it is <0, I go to the left one. If the result is 0, it means I've found a node with a matching key.

I've made an edit to the post with what you've requested. Every node stores a value, I don't understand how I could traverse the BST otherwise.

Every node has a key for the comparison, yes, but where do you store the information that your tree contains (or does not contain) a particular value?

I don't store that information. If I want to know if the BST contains a key, I traverse the BST to find it. If I don't, then the BST does not contain the key.

Oh, right, I was thinking of tries.

During your traversal, instead of doing an ordinary strcmp(input, key) you also check how much of a prefix they share. For each prefix length, you store the first node that you've found whose key has this prefix. You can then use these nodes as starting nodes for finding the respective prefix in a subtree only, instead of having to start over from the root.

Trying this, the computation times seem to be longer, and in my case (~120k strings to find the prefixes of and ~100k keys in the bst) I am missing a few (around 20 out of ~4000) found prefixes when compared to what the naive implementation finds.

@glugau Can you share your implementation, as well as a sample tree where prefixes are not found despite existing? I'm pretty sure the approach is sound, even if the details are a bit fiddly.
